# How to sort a dictionary based on key ascending and value descending if the key and value are made up of strings of multiple chars?

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:
dict_1 = {'ABCDEFG': ['AB'], 'GFE': ['AB']}

I want to sort the dictionary based on value ascending and based on key descending. I have written the following code which I believe to be correct. Unfortunately, out of experience, what I believe to be correct is usually correct only in my specific instance, in short - the code is wrong and there is a smarter way to achieve the searched result.

Code:

```
    dict_1 = {'ABCDEFG': ['AC'], 'GFE': ['AB']}
sorted_1 = sorted(dict_1.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], [-ord(x[0][n]) for n in range(len(x[0]))]), reverse=False)
print(sorted_1)
```

What I expect as an output:
A sorted list based on value first ascending and based on key second if values are equal - descending.

Note:
The key and value will always be strings with more than 1 symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Python's sort is stable, you can do this in two sort steps:

1. sort by descending key
2. sort by ascending values

Equal values will retain the original (descending) order of their respective keys

```
dict1 = {'GFE': ['AB'], 'ABCDEFG': ['AC'], 'XYZ':['AB'] }

sorted1 = sorted(dict1.items(), reverse=True)
sorted1 = sorted(sorted1, key=lambda kv:kv[1])

print(sorted1)

[('XYZ', ['AB']), ('GFE', ['AB']), ('ABCDEFG', ['AC'])]
```

You could also do this in a single line:

```
sorted1 = sorted(sorted(dict1.items(),reverse=True),key=lambda kv:kv[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped!